# Difference betwwen 3-SAT and CNF

Tags: algorithm, boolean, z3, sat

I try to solve SAT problem in SMT-LIB syntax using by Z3 theorem solver, I required to write propositional formula in CNF and find the satisfying values.
I know the concepts but I dont understand implementation. Could you give example about about 3-SAT problem solved by Z3 theorem provers.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An example [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) CNF input file in [DIMACS](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/index-seo.php/SATLINK____DIMACS) format:

File xor.txt:

```
p cnf 3 4
1 2 3 0
1 -2 -3 0
-1 2 -3 0
-1 -2 3 0
```

To find a solution for this *Conjunctive Normal Form*, call `z3`:

```
z3 -dimacs xor.txt
```

The commandline parameter `-dimacs` informs Z3 about the input format.

The resulting output:

```
sat
1 -2 -3
```

This means that the problem is satisfiable with the solution

```
Variable 1 true
         2 false
         3 false
```

[3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) restricts the CNF to clauses with no more than three literals each.

To convert a propositional formula to CNF, you could use tools like [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/).

Comment: Thank you  I need formulas in SMT-LIB syntax. Could you give example in this format,I edited first message

Comment: You might want to consult the [SMT-LIB language document](https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml). CNF and 3-SAT mentioned in the question led me to think that you want to use Z3 as SAT solver.